# How do I create a function to display text using jQuery and does not execute if img src contains 'is.png'?

Tags: jquery, html, image, src

I am wanting to create a function to display text above the "Request Pricing" button for all regions **except** where img src contains 'is.png'. My jQuery code to add the text to the page works when inserted:

```
jQuery(".request-pricing").before("<div class='price-box' style='display:block!important;'><span class='regular-price' id='product-price'><span class='price' itemprop='price'>Starting from 1,123 EUR</span></span></div>");
```

Code for the "Request Pricing" button with "request-pricing" class:

```
<a class="request-pricing fancybox.ajax" data-fancybox-type="ajax" href="/products/distributor/requestPricingForm?product_id=5265"> <button class="sc-button blue">Request Pricing</button> </a>
```

The code when I don't want the function to run (Iceland):

```
<div class="country-flag">
        <a href="/contact-us#country=IS">
            <img src="https://cdn.stemcell.com/media/flag/is.png" alt="Iceland" title="Iceland">
        </a>
        <input type="hidden" class="hidden" id="geo_ip_country_code" name="geo_ip_country_code" value="IS">
    </div>
```

I am not sure how to run my jQuery code so it always executes except if img src contains 'is.png'.

Here is my attempt:

```
if ($(".country-flag img[src*='flag']")).ready(function showprice() {
  $(".request-pricing").before("<div class='price-box' style='display:block!important;'><span class='regular-price' id='product-price'><span class='price' itemprop='price'>Starting from 1,123 EUR</span></span></div>");
}); else {
($(".country-flag img[src*='is.png']")).stop(function showprice() {
}
```

I am just learning jQuery so I appreciate any feedback or resources.

Comment: Can you please include the markup with class `request-pricing`? Does it occur once per `country-flag`? I think that will help clarify your question!

Comment: @DavidFox Yes, occurs once. The text "Starting from 1,123 EUR" is to be displayed above the button "Request Pricing" (code below).

`<a class="request-pricing fancybox.ajax" data-fancybox-type="ajax" href="/products/distributor/requestPricingForm?product_id=5265">
                                            <button class="sc-button blue">Request Pricing</button>
                                        </a>`

Answer (score 1):

I would advise using `.indexOf()` like so:

```
if ($(".country-flag img").attr("src").indexOf("flag")) {
  var pb = $("<div>", {
    class: "price-box"
  }).css("display", "block !important").insertBefore($(".request-pricing"));
  $("<span>", {
    class: "regular-price",
    id: "product-price"
  }).appendTo(pb);
  $("<span>", {
    class: "price",
    itemprop: "price"
  }).html("Starting from 1,123 EUR").appendTo($("span", pb));
} else if($(".country-flag img").attr("src").indexOf("is.png")) {
  // Do a thing
}
```

If it is found, `.indexOf()` will return an integer of 0 or higher. In an `if()` statement, -1 and 0 are evaluated as False and 1 or higher is True.

See More:

- https://api.jquery.com/insertbefore/
- https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp
- https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_if.asp